# How to get owner's name / email using phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am running a phonegap build application version 3.4.0.

Phonegap build has a list of plugins https://build.phonegap.com/plugins where you can find a lot of them for example to send mails, etc.
But i can't see a plugin that retrieve the account information for android devices like the email or name of the owner.

To add a plugin you have a config.xml file in wich you add a line like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer" version="1.4.6" />
```

My problem is that i found a plugin that seems to be useful: https://github.com/seltzlab/AccountList-Phonegap-Android-Plugin but i cannot find a way to include it on phonegap build compilation.

I can see that you can create a custom public plugin http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_contributing_plugins.md.html but i don't need that, i only need to use one, wich is already created.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.